# Activiti Process engine is null

Tags: java, spring, activiti

When I run my java web application on eclipse luna, I'm having a null pointer on process engine. My activiti.cfg.xml file in my classpath. Note that the same project when I run it my eclipseforspring,it works fine. I'm having this issue only in eclipse.

```
  public static List getTaskList() {

   ProcessEngine processEngine = ProcessEngines.getDefaultProcessEngine();

    TaskService taskService = processEngine.getTaskService();
    try {
    taskList=  taskService.createTaskQuery().taskCandidateUser(username).list();
    return taskList;
    } catch(NullPointerException e){
    return null;
   }}
```

and in my activiti.cfg.xml, I have this line:

```
   <bean id="processEngineConfiguration" class="org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.StandaloneProcessEngineConfiguration">
```

Did I miss a jar file?I check it in both ide and it's the same.

Comment: `in my activiti.cfg.xml, I have this line:` Probably the line was gone :-)

Comment: I'm sorry. I just update the post